# Switching to an AFCI breaker, but builder had used a 3 wire/2 breaker setup

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I am looking to bring my finished attic to code and I am told I need to replace my existing 2 15A single pole breakers with 2 AFCI breakers. Builder used 12/3 wire for 2 circuits, one going to HVAC and the other going to receptacles. Black hot wire to one breaker and Red hot to the other and the White Neutral to the. How do I do this with AFCI breakers if each need a neutral?

Comment: What make and model is your panel?

Comment: ^^ It matters. *Seriously.*